# Utilizar Interface com observable

Tags: angular

Criei uma Interface para salvar informação de sessão do usuário para usar com um observable, a idéia e fazer um set quando o usuário faz o login e as outras páginas, e um service pra requisições HTTP farão o get desta Interface. O service para requisição return undefined após dar um get na Interface.

```
export interface ICredential {
    IsLogged?: boolean;
    XAccessToken?: string;
    UserId?: string;
}
```

Página com form para login

```
export class HomePage {
  _ICredential: ICredential;
 
.....

  GoogleSingIn(): void {
    this._SocialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(
      Data => {
      ....

         this._ICredential = {
            XAccessToken: this.XAccessToken,
            UserId: this.UserId,
            IsLogged: true,
          }
      })
     })
  }
```

No service session criei o observable

```
  Session(): Observable<ICredential> {
    return new Observable<ICredential>(observer => {
      observer.next(this._ICredential);
    });
  }
```

no service com requisições HTTP, mando um console.log e me retorna undefined

```
 this._SessionService.Session().subscribe(
      data => { 
        console.log(data.XAccessToken);
        this.XAccessToken = data.XAccessToken  }, 
      error => alert(JSON.stringify(error))
    )
```

Comment: A interface em si não tem muito o haver com o teu problema, quando você se inscreve em Session() a subscription está retornando alguma coisa ? Você está fazendo esta inscrição antes ou depois de ter chamado o método `GoogleSingIn` e quanto tal metodo deve ser chamado? ... A Interface serve simplemente para dizer que formato o seu dado tem, o fato de você estar ou não recebendo alguma coisa não tem haver com a interface

Comment: Session está retornando undefined. Faço o login com GoogleSigIn e na página seguinte eu tento recuperar dados da Interface. Então minha interpretação estava errada quanto a Interface armazenar os dados?

Comment: Exato, interfaces não armazenam nenhum dado a não ser o formato que os dados que implementam a interface devem ter, deixa eu ver se eu entendi bem o problema: 
Na pagina A você faz o login e redireciona o usuário para a página B onde você chama o método `Session()` e espera obter os dados que você armazenou antes, é isso?

Comment: Isto mesmo. Assim como as próximas paginas usarão dados que seriam da ICredential para validar a sessão.

Comment: Desta forma nunca irá funcionar, você definiu o seu `_ICredential` dentro a classe `HomePage` que eu imagino que seja o seu componente, enquanto o seu método `Session` se encontra dentro ao serviço `_SessionService` o qual nunca teve nenhuma inicialização de variável, crie um serviço único ou use o que você já tem no caso `_SessionService` para fazer a autenticação e salvar os valores que você precisa, desta maneira você não perde este dado quando você navega entre páginas.

Comment: Entendi. A ICredential está dentro de uma pasta Interface e realmente uso a HomePage como inicial / login, então criarei dentro desta página o observable para retornar estas informações. A Idéia da _SessionService é para retornar os dados da sessão

Comment: Dentro de home criei uma chamada para o service login e dentro deste criei BehaviorSubject com as informações que preciso durante a sessão do usuário. Postando aqui a solução final para pessoas com pouco conhecimento, como eu rs.

Answer (score 0):

Solução para a minha dúvida. Quando o usuário clica no botão para efetuar login com a rede social do Google, chamo o login service para efetuar o login.

```
 export class HomePage {
  
   GoogleSingIn(): void {
    this._SocialAuthService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(
      Data => {
        this._LoginService.SignIn(Data.email, Data.name);
      })
  }
```

Dentro do login service eu crio BehaviorSubject e após login dou um set com os valores corretos.

```
private IsLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  get _IsLoggedIn() {
    return this.IsLoggedIn.asObservable();
  }

  private Token = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
  get _Token() {
    return this.Token.asObservable();
  }

  private UUID = new BehaviorSubject<any>("");
  get _UUID() {
    return this.UUID.asObservable();
  }


   SignIn(UserEmail: any, UserName: any) {
  
    ...

      this.IsLoggedIn.next(true);
      this.Token.next(this.XAccessToken);
      this.UUID.next(this.UserId);

    })
  }
```